# git: fix commits from a branch created from another branch

Tags: git, github

So there was an existing branch called `some_branch`
I created branch `my_branch` from `some_branch`
now when i push my branch changes it shows all the commits including commits made on `some_branch`

How can i avoid the changes made on `some_branch` so it shows only my changes?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot do that. Any branch includes all commits from the top of the branch back to the initial commit. Why do you want it?

Comment: if you change the target branch to be `some_branch` it would show only the changes in your new branch - although i'm not sure if thats what you are planning to do?... i.e. merge back to `some_branch` and then merge that to master?

Comment: You clearly do not understand how Git works. Please read about the basics.

Comment: @Robbie Thank you so much. That helps. Please add it to answer and i'll mark as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you created `my_branch` off `some_branch` and set up the PR, it defaults `master`as the target branch. So the PR contains all the commits/changes `master` doesn't have.

If you want `some_branch` to contain only the additional commits then you could set the target branch in the PR to `some_branch`.

Then to get the commits into `master`, first merge `my_branch` into `some_branch` and then merge `some_branch` into `master`.

If thats your desired workflow